# Liferay portlet non-liferay JNDI data source null

Tags: oracle, tomcat7, jndi, liferay-6, portlet

For a Liferay 6.2 custom portlet accessing a non liferay Oracle database we are running into an issue where the data source returned is null.

We have configured the tomcat/conf/context.xml

```
<!-- Adding custom New non liferay datasource -->
<Resource name="jdbc/NewPool" 
auth="Container"               
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = 
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dbservernameorip)(PORT = 9999))
(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) 
(SERVICE_NAME = dbSIDorservicename)))"
username="user" 
password="pwd" 
maxActive="35"
maxIdle="10"
maxWait="20000"
removeAbandoned="true"
logAbandoned="true"
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="3600000"
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"
testOnBorrow="true"
testOnReturn="false"
/>
```

The portlet web.xml contains:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle Datasource example</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/NewPool</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

The code for lookup is:

```
String JNDI = "jdbc/NewPool"
_log.debug("JNDI Name  is: " + JNDI);
_log.debug("dataSource in dbConnect is :" + dataSource);
Context context = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)context.lookup("java:/comp/env");
_log.debug("envContext in dbConnect is :" + envContext);
try {
  DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup(JNDI);
```

Liferay can use the context.xml resource with a similar data source for the Liferay Oracle database successfully.

Is some other wiring needed for Liferay portlet to establish a connection to another database?

The same portlet code works on weblogic without the web.xml change. Similar JNDI data source lookup code and configuration works on vanilla tomcat (without liferay) and a plain war (non liferay portlet) file.

**Update:**

I have checked db connections on the server with netstat -an|grep dbport. this does not show an established connection.

I have also tried setting the portal.security.manager.strategy=none in portal-ext.properties. This did not work either.

Any insight is much appreciated as we are kind of stuck here.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to declare your JNDI resource not in Tomcat itself, but in the webapp? I remember I ran into a similar issue, when I tried to install Aperte workflow portlet.

Comment: No I have not yet tried this but its worth a shot. We also found similar Liferay issues and have also reported it to Liferay support. They have been able to reproduce it but no resolution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled over this thread in the Liferay Forum which basically says. oput this in your tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/XXX" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="5000"
          removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="250" validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          username="user2" password="pwd2"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/myOtherDb"/>
```

and this in your context.xml:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/XXX" global="jdbc/XXX" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
```

It should do the trick. If you really asking WHY Liferay can find the jndi resource, but not your portlet:
I have no clue...

Answer (score 1):

We also had some problems using the resource and pools. Since we have very few requests to handle and performance were not a concern for our scenario we used a JDBC connection directly without a pool and it's working fine (we are connecting to a MS Sql server)

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host/dbname";
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String db_userName = PropsUtil.get("jdbc.default.username");
String db_password = PropsUtil.get("jdbc.default.password");

try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, db_userName, db_password);

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()){
        // DO WHAT YOU WANT
        return true;
    }
    rs.close();
}catch(SQLException se){
    //Handle errors for JDBC
    se.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception e){
    //Handle errors for Class.forName
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    //finally block used to close resources
    try{
        if(stmt!=null)
            conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
    }// do nothing
    try{
        if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }//end finally try
}//end try
```

And it's working fine. Username and password are configured in portal-ext.properties (We are using the same account used for liferay own db)

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, its not an option for us to do a direct JDBC Connection long term because of the expected load and performance concerns. We also need to load balance the connection pool to the 2 database cluster nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe we found our issue. It seems like it was a typo.

All references to dataSource need to be changed to ds. There was a code changed.  It turned out the the variable name was not changed to ds in code after the ds variable was declared during troubleshooting the issue.

```
String JNDI = "jdbc/NewPool"
_log.debug("JNDI Name  is: " + JNDI);
_log.debug("dataSource in dbConnect is :" + ds);
Context context = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)context.lookup("java:/comp/env");
_log.debug("envContext in dbConnect is :" + envContext);
try {
  DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup(JNDI);
_log.debug("dataSource in dbConnect is :" + ds)
```

We need to test this out. I will post the results after the final test.